# Angular - Use application theme in library

Tags: angular, typescript, angular6, angular-library

I'm writing an Angular library. I want to use the primary color of application theme in my library. I don't have access to `theme.scss` file, so I can't import that in my component style file. How Can I do this?

Thanks

Comment: I'm afraid that if you don't explain a little bit better anybody would be able to help you. Take a look at this post: https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found it out. You can use app theme variables in SCSS like this:

```css
{ color: var(--app-priamry-color); }
```